# How can I apply Win UI 3 to a traditional Win32 app without rewriting it?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, webkit, winui-3

First of all, thank you for seeing my question. As the title says. How to add some Win UI3 elements to a traditional Win32 application. Because the project itself is very large, and the UI part is composed of Cpp (other parts are composed of languages such as python). It would be very unwise to rewrite it like this. I just want to change the main interface originally composed of cpp to the WinUI3 interface. How do I do it in Visual Studio 2019 (16)?

Comment: Probably rewriting the UI parts.

Comment: Is `webkit` the proper tag for this?

Comment: @drescherjm  I'm very sorry. WebKit is an application (Minibrowser) that wants to add Win UI 3 elements. Because I just want it to work on Windows 10/11.

Answer (score 0):

See Microsoft's [Xaml Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands-cpp) documentation, some interesting Windows Blog [articles](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/11/02/xaml-islands-a-deep-dive-part-1/) and look for [examples](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Islands-Samples) on Github.